# Howto copy MHT (HTML + pictures) data stored in tMemoryStream to tWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, memorystream, mhtml

Howto copy MHT (HTML + pictures) data stored in a TMemoryStream to a TWebBrowser? If I save the MHT from the MemoryStream to disk with:

```
MS.SaveToFile(FName);
```

and then navigate the WebBrowser to this file:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(FName);
```

it works fine.

I want to do it directly, without disk saving.

Comment: Just a wild thought: a .mht file is in fact plain text. So load a TStringList from the TMemoryStream (using LoadFromStream) and then use TWebBrowser's LoadFromStrings to load the TStringList's Text. IOW: `YourStringList.LoadFromStream(YourMemoryStream, <appropriate encoding>); YourBrowser.LoadFromStrings(YourStringList.Text, '');`. I don't know if that works for MHT, or only for plain HTML, sorry. But you could give it a try.

Comment: You can also load a stream into a `TWebBrowser` by navigating it to `about:blank`, then query its `Document` for `IPersistStreamInit` and pass the stream to its `Load()` method (you can convert a `TStream` to `IStream` by using `TStreamAdapter`)

Comment: @Remy: I guess that is the better path. Loading a MHT from a TStringList.Text just shows the plain text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Tried it your way. Loads fine with SHDocVw.TWebBrowser (VCL WebBrowser), but not with the FMX WebBrowser while my way works in FMX but not in VCL. But even your way displays the MHT as plain text. So there is probably no viable alternative to saving to a .mht file and then navigating to that file, as the OP already did. Loading it into the browser directly simply does not tell the browser that it should treat it as MHT and not as HTML.

Comment: The _really_ _really_ hard way to do it is implementing IInternetProtocol. It's a lot of work, some things are really not straight-forward, but I once did, and I'm glad I pulled through, as eventually it has led me to write [xxm](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm#xxm)

Comment: can't think any reason why the FMX browser won't work the same as VCL other than a difference in FEATURE_MIME_SNIFFING settings in registry. If you want your code work with MIME sniffing off, implement IMoniker to provide a url that ends with .mht and load the moniker with IPersistMoniker.